# What can cause a persistent, random, intermittent connectivity issue?

Tags: networking

I am posting this question as a last resort. I have been troubleshooting a connectivity issue with my internet for a few months now. Since April, I have been experiencing 1-3 second loss of internet every 30 minutes to 2 hours. The time period between the losses is entirely random and unpredictable.

This problem happens across multiple different programs and activities. If I am downloading a file, the download will fail (Chrome and Firefox). If I am using a VPN or connecting somewhere via SSH or Remote Desktop, the connection will drop. I often observe the connection dropping over voice chat (Mumble), which has both UDP and TCP options. If I am running UDP mode, voices will cut out and will never come back, but I will not disconnect from the server. If I force TCP mode, I will disconnect from the server and automatically rejoin a few seconds later. If I run a continuous ping test, the issue will present as 1-3 "Request timed out." lines amidst a sea of normal pings to Google.com.

I have fiber-to-the-doorstep municipal internet that connects via a box on the outside of my home that serves as "modem" that I have no physical or software access to. I have been working with them to troubleshoot the problem, to no avail.

I have tried all of the above with the problem still occurring:

- A new router (Cisco Linksys E2500 running DD-WRT, upgraded from Linksys WRT54GL)
- A new network interface card
- Multiple computers (two desktops and a laptop, desktops Windows 7 and laptop Ubuntu Trusty Tahr)
- Connecting directly to the connection from the wall, bypassing the router
- A new Cat5 cable to my computer

My ISP has tried:

- Switching the port on the box on the exterior of my home (which acts as the modem)
- Switching out the board inside the box on the exterior of my home
- Switching the cable that runs from the box into the house
- "Upgrading" me to a higher speed/tier of service by switching my subnet temporarily, which did not fix the problem
- Presumably internal diagnostics/port checking on the other end of the connection (they find no significant packet loss)

Their next step is adding some sort of new box on the exterior of my house that will allow the engineer working my case to see light levels from the fiber in real time. I think I have done everything eliminate the possibility that the problem is in my hardware. What else could I try and/or what could be causing a problem like this?

Update: my previous statement that these cutouts are random appears to have been false. The issue is occurring at the 52 minute mark when my DHCP lease drops and my IP is renewed. While my IP address is not changing, my devices seem to be failing their half-remaining-time lease renewal. The ISP claims a minimum lease time of 60 minutes is set, but my lease remains 51-52 minutes. I am assuming the drops are because my lease is dropping temporarily and requesting a new one. What could be causing my half-remaining-time check-in to fail every time? I expect it is on the ISP side, since it happens with all of my devices and regardless of my router, but I don't know enough about ISP infrastructure to hazard a guess or do any tests.

Comment: Have you tried moving house?

Comment: Are You connected over wire or over Wi-Fi? Or both?

Comment: All are connected over wire. The problem is present on all computers. Moving house is about the only thing I haven't tried!

Comment: Did You try talking to neighbors? Are they also experiencing this?

Comment: I only have one neighbor that I know of with the same ISP, and they are not experiencing the problem. The engineer with my ISP didn't indicate that this was any sort of regular problem. He has tried to dismiss it as "a few lost packets in a couple of hours," but I am puzzled by why a few lost packets is resulting in dropped connections even in a connection-oriented protocol like TCP.

Comment: This is a good one. The only thing left I can think about is some sort of interference with the cat5 cable but that is not likely to happen. I'm like 99% sure that the problem is from your ISP. If I am right, your ISP should have a profile of your connection type in their server, where all of your user-password/settings/speed limits, etc. are configured. I have encountered a similar problem (also with fiber optics) in the past where that profile was misconfigured. You should suggest them to recreate it, if they haven't done it yet.

Comment: @Zoneman It takes far more than a few lost packets to cause connection loss. TCP was designed to gracefully cope with packet loss (up to a point of course). Too bad your engineer sounds like he (a) doesn't know what he's talking about or (b) trying to dupe you.

Comment: Thanks, Divin3. @misha256 That's what I was thinking too. I wasn't sure how a couple of seconds of packet loss (especially if it's not many packets within those few seconds) could result in dropped connections like that.

Comment: Can you try a different isp (i.e. use a free trial). That would prove whether the issue`s with the isp or something your end.

Comment: When I had this exact same problem.  It turns out it was a noisy line (ingress  specifically), and the modem was extremly sensitive to it, and would disconnect. I had them update the firmware and have not had the problem since.  You don't mention what modem you have.  So the first step, get them to upgrade the firmware on the modem, second step get the highest level techician possible out there to look at the problem.

Comment: @misha256 - What I suspect is actually happening is that the cable modem is actually restarting each time an error on the line happens.  The "1-3" seconds of connectivity loss is simply the time between the modem booting and assigning a ip address to the router.

Comment: @JohnLBevan This would require running a new line to my house and installing new cable to at least one point in the home to attach the modem and router to, so I haven't tried it yet. I'm not sure I have a company locally that will do the install for free AND provide a free trial. It might be something to try if I can't get this sorted with my current ISP though.

Comment: @Ramhound It's not a cable modem. I have fiber to the doorstep, so I have no modem in the traditional sense. The role of "modem"/gateway is performed by a box on the outside of my house that I have no access to, software or hardware, except through my ISP. As they (claim to) have replaced the board inside the box during this troubleshooting process, I have to assume it is also running the most recent firmware, but I will double-check with them on that.

Comment: @Zoneman - You might want to indicate that in your question.  If thats the case its unlikely noise on the line, unless its your router doing it, can you elminate router to see if it still happens?  The only other thing that comes to mind is perhaps a dirty power line, in that, the modem is losing power in some capacity.  Can you log into a configuration page of any type, on this gateway, to determine if its generating logs?

Comment: @Ramhound I do indicate in my question that I have fiber-to-the-doorstep municipal internet. I'll clarify regarding the modem/box. Also in my question, I have tried bypassing the router and plugging my computers directly into the line coming into the house, and the problem persists. I have no access to a configuration page directly, but the engineer at the ISP says he has access to logs and statistics, but that he has found no problems.

Comment: @Zoneman - Well I missed it.  Ooops.

Comment: @Ramhound It's ok! I welcome any attempts to help at this point.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like the IP address of something is changing - My next step would be to undertake some monitoring - both of the IP address of the router and the IP address on your computer.

You might want to eliminate the possible issue of DHCP on your computer by providing a static IP address - but I'd suspect the issue is at the ISP side, unless you have lots and lots of devices oveflowing your address space, which seems to me to be less likely.

A change of IP address could explain the TCP/UDP issues symptoms.

Comment: My IP address has stayed consistent with the exception of the period where they switched me to a different subnet to switch me to a higher tier of service, for testing purposes. I have noticed that my DHCP lease time from my ISP is only 52 minutes, but the outages don't seem to coincide with my DHCP renewal either.

Comment: This ended up being close. While my IP was not changing, my DHCP connection to my ISP was the source of the problem. I will write up an explanation for an answer soon.